# TypeError: an integer is required with buffer

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, ip

I'm trying to build a packet sniffer but everytime a try to run this python i get a TypeError an integer is required when i'm trying to read the first 20 byte of the packet.

this is the part of the code that gives me an error:

```
try:
while True:

    #read in a packet
    raw_buffer = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]

    #create an IP Header from the first 20 bytes of the buffer
    ip_header = IP(raw_buffer[0:20])

    #print out the protocol that was detected and the hosts
    print "Protocol: %s %s -> %s" % (ip_header.protocol, ip_header.src_address, ip_header.dst_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the IP header is the first of the received buffer, but maybe it is not. Normally, an Ethernet header is preceding it, so that may be causing the IP constructor to fail.